# Whe I use the react route 4 history, but the console gives the follow warning. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

**warnning:**  ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router}`  instead of `import {HashRouter as Router}`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add your code to the question by copying and pasting the text and [formatting it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)?

Comment: This warning should go with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62583930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning clearly explains what is wrong in your code. `HashRouter` and `BrowserRouter` have their own predefined `history` and hence they do not take history passed explicitly. In order to use `custom history` you can use `Router` from `react-router-dom`

```
import { Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Also if you are using `createBrowserHistory` and not using anywhere else except to pass it to the Router, you may as well use `BrowserRouter` like

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```