# React Router with custom history not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom, history

When I was using BrowserRouter from react-router-dom, My Routes were working. But to use custom history, I replaced BrowserRouter with Router from react-router. After that my Route components are not loading properly but the url is changing properly.
Here is my codes:

AppRouter-JS:----

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router';
// import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history'

import Header from '../components/Header.js';
import Dashboard from '../components/DashboardPage.js'
import CreateExpense from '../components/CreateExpensePage.js';
import EditExpense from '../components/EditExpensePage.js';
import Help from '../components/HelpPage.js';
import PageNotFound from '../components/PageNotFound.js'
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage.js'


export const history = createBrowserHistory();

  const AppRouter = ()=>(
    <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact={true} component={LoginPage}/>
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
        <Route path='/create' component={CreateExpense} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpense}/>
        <Route path='/help' component={Help} />
        <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
  )
  export default AppRouter;
```

HeaderJS:-- (Here we have the NavLinks)

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {LogoutAction} from '../Redux/Actions/AuthActions.js'

export const Header = ({logoutAction})=>(
    <header>
      <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
      <p><NavLink exact activeClassName='active-class' to='/'>Home Page</NavLink></p>
      <p><NavLink activeClassName='active-class' to='/create'>Add Expense</NavLink></p>
      <p><NavLink activeClassName='active-class' to='/help'>Help Page</NavLink></p>
      <button onClick={logoutAction}>Logout</button>
    </header>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=> {
  return {
    logoutAction: ()=> dispatch(LogoutAction())
  }
}

  export default connect(undefined,mapDispatchToProps) (Header);
```

After clicking any NavLink or Link it always opens the PageNotFound component.

Comment: Same here. Setting up a new project on v5.2.0. When I use BrowserRouter everything is good but Router + passing in a history object and only the initial page load switches correctly. Upon subsequent location changes (e.g. clicking on a link) the Switch statement does not seem to match any routes.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 60):

I actually just found my problem, and it might be yours too.

I was on `react-router-dom@5.2.0` and `history@5.0.0`.

react-router 5x is compatible with history 4x. Once I downgraded to `history@4.10.1` everything started working.

Answer (score 2):

Now using useNavigate() hook instead of useHistory() or anything related to history.

You can use like this;

`import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";`

`let navigate = useNavigate();`

`navigate('/detail')`

*Note:Written to update information.*

Answer (score 0):

i used history.goBack("/signup") not history.push("/signup") seems to work for me .