# React Router Link doesn't keep state in custom history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, history.js

In my project I use React Router DOM 5.2.0. I have to use `<Router />` with custom history due to project needs. And this is how it goes:

[Example on Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-sunset-cn4de?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

##### history.js

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

##### useRouter.js

```js
import {
  useParams,
  useRouteMatch,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMemo } from 'react';

import history from './history';
import urlQueriesService from './urlQueriesService';

const useRouter = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  const { location } = history;

  return useMemo(() => ({
    push: history.push,
    replace: history.replace,
    pathname: location?.pathname,

    query: {
      ...urlQueriesService.parse(location?.search),
      ...params,
    },

    match,
    location,
    history,
  }), [params, match, location, history]);
};

export default useRouter;
```

##### AppRoutes.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import useRouter from './useRouter';
import TestPage from './TestPage';
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';

const AppRoutes = () => {
  const { location } = useRouter();
  return (
    <Switch location={location}>
      <Route exact path="/page-1" component={Page1} />
      <Route exact path="/page-2" component={Page2} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default AppRoutes;
```

##### App.jsx

```js
import history from './history';

<Router history={history}>
  <AppRoutes />
</Router>
```

This is the basic setup. `Page1` and `Page2` are cross linking components and look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import useRouter from './useRouter';

const Page1 = () => {
  const { location } = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>

      <div>
        <Link to={{ pathname: '/page-2', state: { prevUrl: location.pathname }}}>Stateful component</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page1;
```

The key part here is `Link` component which has `to` prop with object as value. In this object I define `state: { prevUrl: location.pathname }`, but this `state` is always `null` when I try to access it in `Page2`. The fun thing here is that if I change `<Router />` to be `BrowserRouter` and remove custom `location` from `Switch` - things work very well, meaning `<Link />` does propagate the state. In my case, however, it looks like state is not being handled by the `history` at all.

#### System:

- **Mac** OS 11.4 Big Sur
- **Node** 12.16.2
- **NPM** 6.14.11
- **React** 16.13.1
- **react-router-dom** 5.2.0

Comment: Why aren't you using the `useLocation` hook for the `location` in your `useRouter` custom hook? Why are you trying to use a *different* location on the `Switch` component? You can use `Router` with a `createBrowserHistory` `history` object without issue, I think it's the odd `location` object used on the `Switch` messing it up for you.

Comment: Seems like `Switch` needs to know the `location` object is used to correctly handle component updates. If I remove one - it doesn't render new component.

In `useRouter` I use `location` from `history` object that I created to provide to `Router`, that's why I don't use `useLocation`, because it'd return me location from different object.

I created a sandbox to make it easier to click through https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-sunset-cn4de?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

I just found an answer thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62583930/8080990

Downgrade to `history` version 4, and it works perfect!

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-sunset-cn4de?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)